# doctrine 2 multiple join in one query give me error

Tags: symfony, many-to-many, doctrine-orm

I have query with two MtM relations:

```
        $em = $this->getEntityManager();

        $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
        $qb
            ->select('o')
            ->from('UserBundle:User', 'o')
            ;

        $qb->join('o.organisations', 'org')
            ->where('org.id = :organisation')
            ->setParameter('organisation', $filterData['organisation'])
        ;
        $qb
            ->join('o.scientificDirections', 'd')
            ->where('d.id IN (:directionIds)')
            ->setParameter('directionIds', $directionIds)
            ->orderBy('o.surname')
            ;
        return $qb->getQuery();
```

But it gives me error: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens.
Can anybody explain me what is wrong?
Relation in User model:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="\StrangeBundle\Entity\ScientificDirection")
 *
 */
protected $scientificDirections;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="\StrangeBundle\Entity\Organisation", mappedBy="workers")
 */
protected $organisations;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the reason is because you used `where` twice. That overwrites the first where, which is why it is giving you the parameters number error.

Use `andWhere`